# Polymer 1.0 Paper-Radio-Group sending old value when wrapped in Template

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

When the on-tap function is fired, it captures and logs the previous value.

If `{{item.authd}}` is set as `authnr` its radio button is highlighted however when another button is tapped the `e.currentTarget.selected` displays the older value, not the tapped?

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
  <paper-radio-group selected="{{item.authd}}" on-tap="authChanged" id="{{item.id}}">
  <paper-radio-button name="authnr">N/R</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="pending">Pending</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="authd">Auth</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
</template>
```

```
authChanged: function(e, name) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.selected) // shows old value, not tapped value
}
```

Comment: So you intend to create multiple radio groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following snippet:

```
<dom-module id="x-test">

  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
      <paper-radio-group attr-for-selected="name" selected="{{item.authd}}" on-tap="authChanged" id="{{item.id}}">
      <paper-radio-button name="authnr">N/R</paper-radio-button>
      <paper-radio-button name="pending">Pending</paper-radio-button>
      <paper-radio-button name="authd">Auth</paper-radio-button>
    </paper-radio-group>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>      
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-test',
      properties: {
        data: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
            return [
              {authd: 'authnr',id: 1},
              {authd: 'pending', id:2},
              {authd: 'authd', id:3}
            ]
          }
        },
      },

      authChanged: function(e, name) {
        this.async(function() {
          var model = e.model.item;
          console.log(model.authd, model.id);
        });
      }
    });
  </script> 
</dom-module>
```

I've added `attr-for-selected` to the radio-group to identify which radio-button is selected.

In the `authChanged` callback I've used an `async` method to ensure the `selected` value has changed before we inspect the current item from the model.